# what is the kotlin nested loop syntax issue?

Tags: kotlin

I am getting error for this syntax

```kotlin
  for (i in 0 until 8) {
      for (j in 0 until 8) {

      } println()
  }
```

error is

> For is not an expression, and only expressions are allowed here.

but this is valid

```kotlin
  for (i in 0 until 8) {
      for (j in 0 until 8) {

      }
      println()
  }
```

only thing I changed was where `println()` is called, I have worked with java so I thought that placement should not matter. What is the issue here ?

Comment: Just as an aside: You should prefer the second approach, where the `println()` is on its own line, despite the fact you can make the first approach work with a semicolon. The second approach is more idiomatic and thus more readable.

Comment: @ashish See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#indentation

Comment: yes. thanks for mentioning @Slaw I am used to format on save in my intellij for Java, but starting with Kotlin so getting into some basic issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some testing in Kotlin Playground. Kotlin compiler indeed cannot parse statements that are placed on the same line and not divided by `;`.

For example `10 println("")`
will produce an error: "`Unresolved reference: println`".
Note that `10` actually is an expression, since expressions are code blocks that produce single value.

**The guessing is below:**

The real question is, why Kotlin compiler shows the specific error, which is

```
For is not an expression, and only expressions are allowed here
```

I believe that has something to do with the Kotlin compiler's code parse algorithm. That seems like compiler tries to parse multiple statements on the same line as a single expression. `for` keyword makes it fail right away. However, if you replace `for` loop with a real expression, compiler will highlight the `println` call as something wrong, since it is something excess for an expression.